# How to write universal manipulator using generics?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have interface that defines value and few operations:

```
public interface IValue<T>
{
    T Value { get; }

    void InteractionA(IValue<T> target);
    void InteractionB(IValue<T> target);
    bool Check(IValue<T> target);
}
```

Then i implement class based on that interface

```
public class DoubleValue : IValue<double>
{
    public double Value { get; private set; }

    public bool Check(IValue<double> target)
    {
        // ...
        return false;
    }

    public void InteractionA(IValue<double> target)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void InteractionB(IValue<double> target)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now i want to make universal manipulator that operates on pool of values and uses generics (so i only write it once). Because of the way i want to use this class in the future it cannot be declared static. Moving generic type  into methods also doesn't do any good.
The closest i could get is:

```
public class ValueManipulator<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<IValue<T>> Pool { get; private set; }

    public ValueManipulator(IEnumerable<IValue<T>> pool)
    {
        Pool = pool;
    }

    public void ManipulateA()
    {
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, Pool.Count()))
        {
            IValue<T> firstValue = Pool.ElementAt(i);

            foreach (IValue<T> secondValue in Pool.Skip(i))
            {
                if (firstValue.Check(secondValue))
                    firstValue.InteractionA(secondValue);

                else
                    firstValue.InteractionB(secondValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ManipulateB()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Main problem with this ValueManipulator class is that i need to know T of IValue used in DoubleValue (in this case double). So it looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ValueManipulator<double> doubleManipulator = new ValueManipulator<double>();
    doubleManipulator.Manipulate(ProvideDoubles());
}

private static IEnumerable<DoubleValue> ProvideDoubles()
{
    yield return new DoubleValue();
    yield return new DoubleValue();
    yield return new DoubleValue();
}
```

How do i make ValueManipulator so user does not need to know what type was used in value implementation?

Comment: You could simplify your loops `int i = 1; foreach(var first in pool) { foreach(var second in pool.Skip(i)) {....} i++;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your `ValueManipulator<T>` has no state, as appears to be your case according to your code snippets, then simply make the methods generic instead of the class, that way you can leverage type inference.

```
public class ValueManipulator
{
    public void Manipulate<T>(IEnumerable<IValue<T>> pool)
    {
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, pool.Count()))
        {
            IValue<T> firstValue = pool.ElementAt(i);

            foreach (IValue<T> secondValue in pool.Skip(i))
            {
                if (firstValue.Check(secondValue))
                    firstValue.InteractionA(secondValue);

                else
                    firstValue.InteractionB(secondValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
ValueManipulator myManipulator = new ValueManipulator();
myManipulator.Manipulate(ProvideDoubles()); //type inference will figure out T is double
```

If this is a valid solution then consider making `ValueManipulator` a static class:

```
ValueManipulator.Manipulate(ProvideDoubles());
```

P.D. Please follow advice in commentaries and change `ValueType` to some other name thats less confusing.

*UPDATE* After your latest edit to your question, where you clearly state that `ValueManipulator<T>` *does* have state, the solution seems to be implementing a static factory class:

```
public static class ValueManipulator
{
     public static ValueManipulator<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<IValue<T>> pool)
         => new ValueManipulator<T>(pool);
}

public class ValueManipulator<T> { ... }
```

And again you let type inference do its job:

```
var doubleManipulator = ValueManipulator.Create(ProvideDoubles());
```

Comment: You're right, it does look like ValueManipulator have no state but its oversimplified method of what im currently working on (and there is instance required). Ill update my question.

Comment: this is a solution indeed.